# Are isomers and stereoisomers the same thing?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers

I am doing a presentation regarding Stereochemistry, and I am a little confused with the terminology. My question is:

Are isomers and stereoisomers the same thing? Do they differ from each other?

Comment: A stereoisomer is a class of isomers. There are others such as enantiomers, diastereomers etc.

Comment: Both enantiomers and diastereomers are subsets of stereoisomers, I would not say that they are "separate classes" from stereoisomers. However there are isomers that are not stereoisomers; a simple example is [dimethyl ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_ether) vs [ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol): an example of [functional group isomerism](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/basicorg/isomerism/structural.html)